# ASP.NET Core OAuth2.0. Calling external API on behalf of the user

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-core

sorry for the long question here, but it feels like I googled everything around the topic...

I have `OpenID Connect` - compatible 3rd-party endpoint (service `A`) which I want to use as identity provider in my ASP.NET Core MVC application. The service support `Implicit` and `Code Flow`. No problem at this moment. Furthermore, I want to be able to call service `A`'s api on behalf of the logged in user. I know it relatively easy to do from within `Controller` via:

```
var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
var client = new HttpClient();
client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
var content = await client.GetAsync("https://A.com/api");
```

But if I want to distribute such an access between, let's say, few micro-services (or if I want to schedule a background delayed job), some questions appear:

1. How could i share "access_token" / "refresh_token" in this scenario? Should I handle OAuth events and persist tokens somewhere? Any suggestions on this?
2. Where are tokens stored when we specify `SaveTokens = true` in a middleware?

I appreciate any help on this, seems to be a popular case but not enough info on that across the web.

Comment: asked this very question myself at a conference and got this reply ... part 2 first as that’s easy ... when you do save tokens = true they are saved in the cookie. Part 1 is a design choice, which is why material on it so scarce ... I have seen people save in storage or use it while it lasts, as how long you can use the token to call the API is not dependent on your cookie lifetime rather on the life time of the access token ... hope we get a better answer here ...

Answer (score 1):

There are several sources for this.  Take a look at:
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/

Also there are some Pluralsight courses on this subject. For example:

Getting Started with ASP.NET Core and OAuth by Filip Ekberg (https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/asp-dot-net-core-oauth/table-of-contents).

There is the Microsoft Virtual Academy class, Introduction to IdentityServer for ASP.NET Core, at https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/introduction-to-identityserver-for-aspnet-core-17945?l=oygMZtBPE_5806218965.

I hope this helps.